# Finding lowest and second lowest values within selection, using expressions QGIS 3.24

Tags: qgis-plugins, expression, array, network-analysis, qgis-network-analysis

I need to calculate the closest and second closest point in one layer, measured from points in another layer. I have used Qgis Network Analysis "OD Matrix as table from layers" which gives me a nice matrix of all the distances between all origins to all destinations. I am trying to use expressions to get only the closest and second closest distance (that is, the lowest and second lowest value in the field Total_cost) for each origin_ID.

This expression:

```sql
array_first(
    array_sort(
        array_remove_all( 
            array_agg("total_cost"), 
            minimum(  "total_cost" )
        )
    )
)
```

gives me the second lowest values among all rows in Total_cost, but how do I limit it to search only among the values belonging to Origin_ID 1 etc?

In my example there is only five origins but I need to be able to do this with hundreds origins so it needs to be automatized in some way.

Another option would be to find a network analysis tool where I could choose to only include the closest and second closest point, is there something like that?
[image]

Comment: [`minimum()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#minimum) function also has the `group_by:=` argument

Comment: Ok, how would that expression look like?

Comment: `minimum("total_cost", group_by:="origin_id")`

Comment: Thanks! I had to group array_agg to. Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I least I get a correct result: array_first(array_sort(array_remove_all( array_agg(   "total_cost",group_by:= "origin_id"   ), minimum(  "total_cost",group_by:= "origin_id"  ))))